# C# Alternatives to Databases for Frequently Changing Data?

Tags: c#, database, transactions

I am writing an application that will perform analytics on logs for the purpose of graphical display.

Each line of data will be analyzed and counters for different tracked metrics will be updated.

For instance, the following line:

```
[01:15:45] WARNING Application1 Error1 Message Text Goes Here
```

Would translate to the following updated metrics:

- +1 Log received during Hour 01
- +1 Log received during Minute 15
- +1 Log received during Second 45
- +1 WARNING severity received
- +1 Application1 application received
- +1 Error1 error received

Depending on the underlying data architecture that single line could end up being 6 INSERT/UPDATE statements. As the number of metrics increases so does the load on the database. What if I wanted to track 30 other things about the above line? That would be 30 statements, and depending on the database size, UPDATEs could take a while.

The easiest way I can think to store this data is simply as objects during the application execution, except I'm now constrained by memory limits. In addition, when the application restarts it would have to parse the entire data set over again.

Are there other database-like technologies out there for managing data of this type? The only thing I can think that makes this data "special" is the fact that there will be a LARGE number of small changes. Since this tool will be single-threaded there is no immediate concern for the data to be transaction-ally sound.

Is there a term for this type of data or solution that would help search for a solution? Surely someone has come across this type of need before.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are thinking to store in this 'database' alternative. If it is just a count that doesn't seems to be a big deal for any kind of current database tool.

Comment: Any popular database can store the data yes, my question is more around better options for storing that that changes very often. There is overhead in submitting a SQL command that hurts the main application's execution time. That's not such a big deal if you read a line and update a line counter. It IS a big deal when you read thousands of lines and for each line update 30 "count" metrics.

Comment: I see, but then, what stops you to read the counters from the database at the beginning of your application, read the file and update the counters in memory and when you finish update just one time the database? You could also prepare a separate thread to update the database at set intervals with the current values of your counters (perhaps adding a bookmark to remember the point reached in your input file) Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Your metrics come from calculations performed on the data. Since you seem to have control over where and how these calculations are performed, why bother the client with more than one insert? You could update metrics dynamically by calculating them in the SQL queries (all RDBMSs have aggregate functions like `COUNT`), or in batches and cache them in reporting tables, or in triggers when rows are inserted. A good database will do what you want.

Comment: @dartonw , could you elaborate on features I may want to look into? The consensus here seems to be that I should continue to use a standard RDBMS and compress my database changes into concise INSERT/UPDATE statements. Instead of going back to the database for every line, parse a few hundred and then run the SQL to bring the database up to speed. I will go back to the drawing board with that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, use Custom Objects and whenever you reach 30 lines serialize it to disk via XML or Binary serialization then free memory, so in this case you will have only 30 lines to work at a time. at the end of each day or when you are finished processing lines, create a thread or process to deserialize the data and BULK insert them into database which will only require one DB hit to insert many rows.